# jQuery/javascript search object and return found key

Tags: jquery, object, search

I have found this really good function to search an object - works a treat and in normal circumstances would be exactly what I am looking for as it returns an array of objects matching the search criteria.

```
function getObjects(obj, key, val){
  var objects = [];
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
      if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {          
         objects = objects.concat(arguments.callee(obj[i], key, val));    
      } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val){
        objects.push(obj);
    }
  }
  return objects;
}
```

As said 'nice and sweet' (well I think so) BUT what I really need to do is also return the key for the 'found' objects.

Example:

```
var obj = {'key1':{obj1},'key2':{obj2},'key3':{obj3},'key4':{obj4}  }
```

so my 'search' would be

```
getObjects(obj, key-to-find, val-to-find)
```

The 'search' key:value pair would be in say {obj1} or {obj3} i.e. not at the 'first' level. How can I adapt the function above to give me the result

```
[{'key1':{obj1},'key3':{obj3} }]
```

Suggestions please.  Many thanks

Comment: `[{'key1':{obj1},'key3':{obj3} }]`: Is there any reason why you want an array of a single object, instead of just an object directly?

Comment: Hi terry no reason at all ' why you want an array of a single object' what I will/would need is the single object if it's in an array that's ok also - as I will need to loop through the results anyhow - so {'key1':{obj1},'key3':{obj3} } is perfectly acceptable

Comment: How deep is your nesting? That's because your current script can search for key value matches that are nested arbitrarily deep.

Comment: Terry - generally one as per example var obj = {'key1':{obj1},'key2':{obj2},'key3':{obj3},'key4':{obj4}  } and occassionally 2

Comment: If it's a 2-level nested object, what key do you want to return?

Comment: It would be the 'parent key so e.g. var obj = {'key1':{'keyl1':{objl1}},'key2':{'keyl2':{objl2}},'key3':{'keyl3':{objl3}},'key4'{'keyl4':{objl4}} so in this case it would be keyl1,keyl3 etc